# Image not showing up in pygame in python 3.6.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, pygame, python-3.6

I am using Pygame in Python 3.6.5 on win32, and my MarioGround.png is not showing up. I have two images yet, one of them is working and the other one isn't. I am getting no errors, either. Here is my complete code yet (to be worked on):

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
sky_blue = (0,150,225)
green = (0,255,0)

displayWidth = 800

displayHeight = 600
#Final :- pygame.display.set_mode((1365, 1050))
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((displayWidth,displayHeight))
pygame.display.set_caption('Super Mario')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


crashed = False

timeOut = False

Quit = False

#50,75
marioStanding = pygame.image.load('Super_Mario_Standing2.png').convert()
marioStanding = pygame.transform.scale(marioStanding, (displayWidth//16,displayHeight//8))

ground = pygame.image.load('MarioGround.png')

def Stand(mx,my):
    gameDisplay.blit(marioStanding,(mx,my))

mx = (displayWidth * 0.45)
my = (displayHeight * 0.8)

def makeGround(gx,gy):
    gameDisplay.blit(ground,(gx,gy))

gx = (displayHeight * 0.45)
gy = (displayWidth * 0.8)

while not crashed and not timeOut and not Quit:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            Quit = True

    print (event)

    gameDisplay.fill(sky_blue)
    makeGround(gx,gy)
    Stand(mx,my)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(24)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

My Super_Mario_Standing2.png is appearing, though MarioGround.png is not. Here as links to both of them: MarioGround.png: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Jz7zTI5Cukv8fXlmyOEkwJTOTkuxIGUP

Super_Mario_Standing.png: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1eUDAin-BUUzi6l-DgxHrf9v8JP8kdAPt

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've mixed up the `displayWidth` and `displayHeight` variables and that means the `gy` variable is 640 (below the screen). Just swap them (also, there's no need for parentheses here):

```
gx = displayWidth * 0.45
gy = displayHeight * 0.8
```